# Multiplying within #define gives strange values

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I write a code for Arduino Nano and I experience this weird behaviour:

```cpp
#define     GREAT      (60 * 60000)
#define     STRANGE     (60 * 6000)
#define     ZERO_X      (60 * 1000)

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(GREAT);      // Prints 3600000, that's correct
    Serial.println(STRANGE);    // Prints 32320, thats wrong
    long zerox = ZERO_X;
    Serial.println(zerox);      // Prints -5536, thats also wrong, obviously
}

void loop() {}
```

What is going on?

I use MSVS2019 Comunity with vMicro

Comment: What do you get for `sizeof((60 * 6000))`?

Comment: Arduino? I believe it's integer has 2 bytes only. So `6000*60` is an integer overflow. `60000` on the other is too big for signed 2-byte integer thus it is interpreted as `long` automatically - henceforth `60*60000` is properly computed.

Comment: @ALX23z it depends on arduino board ie CPU, for Nano it is 2 bytes indeed.

Comment: I can use `uint32_t` instead of `long` or `Serial.print(ZERO_X);` directly, it does not matter. The result is wrong. `(sizeof(60 * 6000))` gives 2.

Comment: Read the datasheet for your part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use integer literals to define your values, and as described in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) type of literal depends on where it can fit. According to [specs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/)

> On the Arduino Uno (**and other ATmega based boards**) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value.

(emphasis is mine) Arduino Nano has CPU with 2 bytes `int` - `60`, `6000` and `1000` fit in signed integer and such type is used. Though neither values of `60 * 6000` nor `60 * 1000` can fit in 2 bytes `int` so you get integer overflow with UB and unexpected values.

On another side `60000` does not fit into `signed int` of 2 bytes, so it gets type `long` with 4 bytes and `60000 * 60` fits there so you get expected result. To fix your problem you can just specify suffixes:

```
#define     GREAT      (60 * 60000L)
#define     STRANGE     (60 * 6000L)
#define     ZERO_X      (60 * 1000L)
```

and force them all to be type `long`. It is not necessary to do it for `60000`, but it is better to have it for consistency.

For your code change:

```
long zerox = ZERO_X;
```

this line does not solve the issue as after macro substitution it is equal to:

```
long zerox = (60 * 1000);
```

and it does not help, as first calculations with type `int` are done on the right side of initialization, overflow happens and then `int` is promoted to `long`. To fix it you need to convert to long one of the arguments:

```
 long zerox = 60 * static_cast<long>(1000);
```

or use suffix as suggested before.

Comment: Does it mean that the type is determined by the biggest vaule or by the rightmost value?

Comment: @Combinatix You can find rules on how types converted and type of result determined here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion pay attention to "Integral promotion"